# pdb: Automatically append to sys.path

Tags: python, pdb

After modularising a python application it's quite annoying to me that I constantly have to add the paths to the sub packages to to `sys.path`. I.e. my workflow to use `pdb` is currently

1. switch from `python [my-script]` to `python -m pdb [my-script]`.
2. `import sys`
3. `sys.path.append([full path to subdirectory where [module-XY] lies])`
4. `b [module-XY]:[line]`

What's your recommendation to automate (2) and (3)? I'd prefer a solution in the following order:

1. something that I can check into git, so it works automatically for everyone / on every device that's used for development.
2. an environment variable or some setup code that I can put to my `.bashrc`, rather than doing some wrapper script around pdb.
3. some virtual-env setup.

Currently I'm thinking about searching for python packages recursively below the working Dir and adding them in a script. Is there some best practice around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, apparently the way to solve this, is using [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH). Either in your `~/.bashrc` or in the `bin/activate` script of your virtualenv, put your module source directories by amending the path as follows:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:[MY-PATH-1]:[...]:[MY-PATH-N]"
```

Source your `bashrc` afterwards or deactivate/activate your virtualenv. Check that it works by running pdb and printing all search paths with `import sys; sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

One other way (depending on usecase maybe a bit less convenient):

always specify your breakpoint with full path, e.g.

```
b foo/bar/bar:39
```

note: the .py file extension is not needed to specify the breakpoint.

Note: writing it like `b foo.bar.bar:39` does *not* work.